# Синтаксис записи в трехмерный массив?

Tags: c#

Всем - доброго времени!
Вот, начал учить Шарп, дошло дело до массивов...
Нашел задачку, на просторах рунета:

> Создать трехмерный массив, и заполнить его цифрами от 1 до 9.

Вроде все просто... Но нифига нигде не могу найти, как в Шарпе, через вложенные FOR-ы вписать именно конкретную цифру...

Получился вот такой код:

```
namespace Arrays
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int z = 0, x = 0, y = 0;
            int[,,] arrays = new int[8, 8, 8];

            for (int i = 0; i <= arrays.Length; i++)
            {
                x++;
                Console.WriteLine("x = " + x);
                for (int j = 0; j <= arrays.Length; j++ )
                {
                    y++;
                    Console.WriteLine("y = " + y);
                    for (int k = 0; k <= arrays.Length; k++)
                    {
                        z++;
                        Console.WriteLine("z = " + z);
                        arrays[i, j, k] = [z, x, y];
                    }
                }
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Уже неделю читаю всякие чудо-сайты по Шарпу, но там нигде нет ничего похожего.
Сам понимаю, что ошибка в синтаксисе написания массива, но что то нигде не могу найти, как выглядит синтаксис записи в массив...
Везде с циклом `for` используется одномерный массив, либо чтение массива. Конкретно синтаксиса записи... Ну, либо я туплю, либо ее никто не знает :)

Кто может, подскажите, как это должно выглядеть, и накидайте плиз, ссылок, что почитать по многомерным массивам... Только не с ближайших 5 страниц в гугле, там я уже все просмотрел :)

Comment: @Duracell — «проблемы с тем-то» — это плохой заголовок для вопроса.

Comment: А что вы конкретно в массив хотите записать? Например: `arrays[i, j, k] = ((x * 8) + y) * 8 + z`, у вас ведь массив типа `int`, значит справа должно быть просто одно число. Каждый элемент массива - это целое число.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[,,] array = new int[8, 8, 8];

    for (int i = 0; i < array.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < array.GetLength(1); j++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < array.GetLength(2); k++)
            {
                array[i, j, k] = i * 8 * 8 + j * 8 + k;
                Console.WriteLine($"array[{i},{j},{k}] = {array[i, j, k]}");
            }
        }
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

- Координатные индексы пишутся наоборот `z, y, x`, а не `x, y, z`. Вообще чтобы не путаться, не используйте "x,y..." для названий индексов, это источник ошибок.
- Заводить дубликаты индексаторов было лишним.
- Получить длину по измерению можно `.GetLength(N)` где N - номер измерения от старшего к младшему. Для двухмерного например 0 это строка, 1 - колонка. `.Length` это общее количество элементов в массиве, суммарно по всем измерениям.

```
array[0,0,0] = 0
array[0,0,1] = 1
array[0,0,2] = 2
array[0,0,3] = 3
array[0,0,4] = 4
array[0,0,5] = 5
array[0,0,6] = 6
array[0,0,7] = 7
array[0,1,0] = 8
array[0,1,1] = 9
array[0,1,2] = 10
array[0,1,3] = 11
...
array[3,0,2] = 194
array[3,0,3] = 195
array[3,0,4] = 196
array[3,0,5] = 197
array[3,0,6] = 198
array[3,0,7] = 199
array[3,1,0] = 200
...
array[7,7,3] = 507
array[7,7,4] = 508
array[7,7,5] = 509
array[7,7,6] = 510
array[7,7,7] = 511
```

`8 x 8 x 8 = 512` - всё верно